# Challenging integral with four sinc functions and an exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to know if this is possible to determine the following integral explicitly (e.g. as a polynomial):

$$ I_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}(\gamma,f)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi(v+k_1))}{\pi(v+k_1)} \frac{\sin(\pi(v+k_2))}{\pi(v+k_2)} \frac{\sin(\pi(v+k_3))}{\pi(v+k_3)} \frac{\sin(\pi(v\gamma+k_4(\gamma-1)))}{\pi(v\gamma+k_4(\gamma-1))}e^{j2\pi v f} dv \ , $$

where $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gamma,f \in \mathbb{R}$.

A first simplification that comes to mind is:

$$ I_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}(\gamma,f)= \frac{(-1)^{k_1}(-1)^{k_2}(-1)^{k_3}(-1)^{k_4}}{\pi^4} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi v)^3\sin(\pi\gamma(v+k_4))}{(v+k_1)(v+k_2)(v+k_3)(v\gamma+k_4(\gamma-1))} e^{j2\pi v f} dv \ , $$

but then I am unsure about the next steps. Do you have any idea? Thank you so much!

Comment: do any Computer Algebra Systems give you a result? Is there any reason to assume a sane closed form exists?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fourier transform? This integral is the Fourier transform of the product of the 4 sincs. In the Fourier domain, a sinc becomes a rectangle and multiplication becomes a convolution, which should allow to compute the integral.

Comment: The problem that occurs in the frequency domain is that the rectangle function are multiplied with an exponential due to time shift. Without the time shift, e.g. when $k_1=k_2=k_3=k_4=0$, this integral leads to a simple polynomial in $f$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Is the exponential a real problem? Without having written it down, it seems still possible to do the convolution. It will be messy with possibly a lot of case distincitions, but seems feasible. If this is not the case, I might move on to ask the same question as @FShrike